# Каким образом сопоставить записи друг с другом?

Tags: sql, oracle

Проблема в том, что есть записи, которые по сути одно и то же, но имеют разные ID.

Есть следующая таблица:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8176/1

```
create table TEST 
( 
  id int,
  name char(200),
  phase int,
  year int
);

insert into test values (1, 'One', 1, 2014);
insert into test values (2, 'One', 2, 2014);
insert into test values (3, 'One', 3, 2014);
insert into test values (4, 'One', null, 2013);
insert into test values (5, 'One', null, 2013);
insert into test values (6, 'One', null, 2013);
```

Необходима в случайном порядке объединить записи. Так, чтобы были по две записи с одинаковым ID, но так, чтобы у каждой записи, где написана фаза была запись без фазы.

Comment: Дополните, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос результатом, который вы бы хотели наблюдать. Рекомендуется, в том числе, прямо в вопросе указывать схему базы данных и тестовое наполнение. Вы можете воспользоваться [этим](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/1037661) вопросом, как инструкцией.

Comment: Что-то типа [этого](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a8176/5)?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, да. Update запрос, который бы внес изменения есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как никто не решился написать ответ, я возьму информацию из комментариев и отвечу сам на данный вопрос. Для того, чтобы объединить записи надо воспользоваться следующим запросом:

```
select 
  row_number() over (partition by year order by phase) as id,
  name,
  phase,
  year
from TEST
order by id, year
```

Он позволит получить все сторонние параметры для `update`-запроса и само новое значение при помощи функции `row_number`. Это касательно приведенного мною примера. Если же запрос и таблицы сложнее, то можно воспользоваться функцией `first_value(ID)`.

Далее достаточно создать `merge` запрос или же воспользоваться скриптовым языком, чтобы в цикле пройти по каждой записи и применить изменения.